# Handle a texture in opengl and cut it in many tiles

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

my question is this:
I have loaded an image as texture in openGL (LWJGL) and each time I call the draw method I am able to select what position of the tileset i want to be shown (in my case is a specific frame of an animation of a sprite), I want to know if it is best to read the entire tileset and cut it into smaller tileset only of a single sprite or is the same to handle the whole image.

actually I load the entire image in a texture for each tile and every time it is drawn each tile works with GL_QUADS on the entire tileset.

A tileset can contain many tiles and many animated tiles.

I used to work with images, reading a big one and putting it into the tileset object and then separating each single tile, cutting the image and putting the cutted piece in the tile.

I can't understand if it's the same with the texture.

In that case what's the metod to create a new texture starting that is a cut of an existing question?

What I want to do is this:

MAP loads TILESET
TILESET loads whole IMAGE
cut the image in many little images (textures)
TILE will have only a small texture, part of the big one.

each time is drawn each tile will handle only a smaller tile. Is that correct or is the same if I pass the whole tileset to each tile telling it only what part to show the user?

This is my TileSet class:

```
package mh.map;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

import mh.GameWindow;
import tiled.util.TileCutter;

public class TileSet implements Iterable<Tile> {
private String              base;
final private Vector<Tile>  tiles   = new Vector<Tile>();
private long                tilebmpFileLastModified;
private TileCutter          tileCutter;
private Rectangle           tileDimensions;
private int                 tileSpacing;
private int                 tileMargin;
private int                 tilesPerRow;
private String              externalSource;
private File                tilebmpFile;
private String              name;
private Color               transparentColor;
private Image               tileSetImage;

private Texture             texture;

public TileSet() {
    this.tileDimensions = new Rectangle();
}

public void importTileTexture(String ref, int width, int height, int spacing, int margin) {
    try {
        this.texture = GameWindow.getTextureLoader().getTexture(ref);
        int texWidth = this.texture.getImageWidth();
        int texHeight = this.texture.getImageHeight();
        int tilePerRow = texWidth / width;
        int rows = texHeight / height;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tilePerRow; j++) {
                Tile t = new Tile(this, j, i);
                this.addNewTile(t);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to load texture: " + ref);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int addTile(Tile t) {
    if (t.getId() < 0) {
        t.setId(this.tiles.size());
    }


    if (this.tileDimensions.width < t.getWidth()) {
        this.tileDimensions.width = t.getWidth();
    }

    if (this.tileDimensions.height < t.getHeight()) {
        this.tileDimensions.height = t.getHeight();
    }

    this.tiles.add(t);
    t.setTileSet(this);

    return t.getId();
}

public void addNewTile(Tile t) {
    t.setId(-1);
    this.addTile(t);
}

public void removeTile(int i) {
    this.tiles.set(i, null);
}

public int size() {
    return this.tiles.size();
}

public int getMaxTileId() {
    return this.tiles.size() - 1;
}

public Tile getTile(int i) {
    try {
        return this.tiles.get(i);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
    }
    return null;
}

public Tile getFirstTile() {
    Tile ret = null;
    int i = 0;
    while ((ret == null) && (i <= this.getMaxTileId())) {
        ret = this.getTile(i);
        i++;
    }
    return ret;
}

public Texture getTexture() {
    return this.texture;
}

}
```

This is Tile.java

```
package mh.map;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import mh.GameWindow;
import mh.interfaces.IImage;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;


public class Tile implements IImage {
/**
 * The texture that stores the image for this sprite (not just one frame)
 * @deprecated Use instead {@link TileSet#getTexture()}
 */
private Texture     texture;
private int         id;
private TileSet     set;
private Properties  prop;
private int         offsetX;
private int         offsetY;

/**
 * Creates a new Tile with a reference to the <code>TileSet</code> and a specified position in that specific set.
 * 
 * @param ts
 *            The TileSet
 * @param texX
 *            The x position of the tile in the tileset (in tile unit)
 * @param texY
 *            The y position of the tile in the tileset (in tile unit)
 */
public Tile(TileSet ts, int texX, int texY) {
    this.set = ts;
    this.offsetX = texX;
    this.offsetY = texY;
    this.texture = ts.getTexture();
}

@Override
public int getWidth() {
    return this.texture.getImageWidth();
}

@Override
public int getHeight() {
    return this.texture.getImageHeight();
}

public void draw(double x, double y) {
    GL11.glPushMatrix();

    this.texture.bind();

    GL11.glTranslated(x, y, 0);
    GL11.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    {
                    // TODO, USE OFFSETS TO DRAW THE CORRECT PIECE OF THE TEXTURE
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, this.texture.getHeight());
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, 32);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(this.texture.getWidth(), this.texture.getHeight());
        GL11.glVertex2f(32, 32);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(this.texture.getWidth(), 0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(32, 0);
    }
    GL11.glEnd();

    // restore the model view matrix to prevent contamination
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}

public void setId(int i) {
    if (i >= 0) {
        this.id = i;
    }
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public Properties getProperties() {
    return this.prop;
}

public void setProperties(Properties p) {
    this.prop = p;
}

public void setTileSet(TileSet ts) {
    this.set = ts;
}
}
```

And this is the textureloader:

```
package mh.map;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

/**
 * @author Kevin Glass
 * @author Brian Matzon
 * @author Gianmarco Laggia
 */
public class TextureLoader {
/** The table of textures that have been loaded in this loader */
private final HashMap<String, Texture>  table   = new HashMap<String, Texture>();

/** The colour model including alpha for the GL image */
private final ColorModel                glAlphaColorModel;

/** The colour model for the GL image */
private final ColorModel                glColorModel;

/**
 * Create a new texture loader based on the game panel
 */
public TextureLoader() {
    this.glAlphaColorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), new int[] { 8, 8, 8, 8 }, true, false,
            Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

    this.glColorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), new int[] { 8, 8, 8, 0 }, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE,
            DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
}

/**
 * Create a new texture ID
 * 
 * @return A new texture ID
 */
private int createTextureID() {
    IntBuffer tmp = this.createIntBuffer(1);
    GL11.glGenTextures(tmp);
    return tmp.get(0);
}

/**
 * Load a texture
 * 
 * @param resourceName
 *            The location of the resource to load
 * @return The loaded texture
 * @throws IOException
 *             Indicates a failure to access the resource
 */
public Texture getTexture(String resourceName) throws IOException {
    Texture tex = this.table.get(resourceName);

    if (tex != null) {
        return tex;
    }

    tex = this.getTexture(resourceName, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, // target
            GL11.GL_RGBA, // dst pixel format
            GL11.GL_LINEAR, // min filter (unused)
            GL11.GL_LINEAR);

    this.table.put(resourceName, tex);

    return tex;
}

/**
 * Load a texture into OpenGL from a image reference on disk.
 * 
 * @param resourceName
 *            The location of the resource to load
 * @param target
 *            The GL target to load the texture against
 * @param dstPixelFormat
 *            The pixel format of the screen
 * @param minFilter
 *            The minimising filter
 * @param magFilter
 *            The magnification filter
 * @return The loaded texture
 * @throws IOException
 *             Indicates a failure to access the resource
 */
public Texture getTexture(String resourceName, int target, int dstPixelFormat, int minFilter, int magFilter) throws IOException {
    int srcPixelFormat = 0;

    // create the texture ID for this texture
    int textureID = this.createTextureID();
    Texture texture = new Texture(target, textureID);

    // bind this texture
    GL11.glBindTexture(target, textureID);

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = this.loadImage(resourceName);
    texture.setWidth(bufferedImage.getWidth());
    texture.setHeight(bufferedImage.getHeight());

    if (bufferedImage.getColorModel().hasAlpha()) {
        srcPixelFormat = GL11.GL_RGBA;
    } else {
        srcPixelFormat = GL11.GL_RGB;
    }

    // convert that image into a byte buffer of texture data
    ByteBuffer textureBuffer = this.convertImageData(bufferedImage, texture);

    if (target == GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D) {
        GL11.glTexParameteri(target, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minFilter);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(target, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magFilter);
    }

    // produce a texture from the byte buffer
    GL11.glTexImage2D(target, 0, dstPixelFormat, this.get2Fold(bufferedImage.getWidth()), this.get2Fold(bufferedImage.getHeight()), 0, srcPixelFormat,
            GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureBuffer);

    return texture;
}

/**
 * Get the closest greater power of 2 to the fold number
 * 
 * @param fold
 *            The target number
 * @return The power of 2
 */
private int get2Fold(int fold) {
    int ret = 2;
    while (ret < fold) {
        ret *= 2;
    }
    return ret;
}

/**
 * Convert the buffered image to a texture
 * 
 * @param bufferedImage
 *            The image to convert to a texture
 * @param texture
 *            The texture to store the data into
 * @return A buffer containing the data
 */
private ByteBuffer convertImageData(BufferedImage bufferedImage, Texture texture) {
    ByteBuffer imageBuffer = null;
    WritableRaster raster;
    BufferedImage texImage;

    int texWidth = 2;
    int texHeight = 2;

    // find the closest power of 2 for the width and height
    // of the produced texture
    while (texWidth < bufferedImage.getWidth()) {
        texWidth *= 2;
    }
    while (texHeight < bufferedImage.getHeight()) {
        texHeight *= 2;
    }

    texture.setTextureHeight(texHeight);
    texture.setTextureWidth(texWidth);

    // create a raster that can be used by OpenGL as a source
    // for a texture
    if (bufferedImage.getColorModel().hasAlpha()) {
        raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, texWidth, texHeight, 4, null);
        texImage = new BufferedImage(this.glAlphaColorModel, raster, false, new Hashtable<String, Texture>());
    } else {
        raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, texWidth, texHeight, 3, null);
        texImage = new BufferedImage(this.glColorModel, raster, false, new Hashtable<String, Texture>());
    }

    // copy the source image into the produced image
    Graphics g = texImage.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, texWidth, texHeight);
    g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);

    // build a byte buffer from the temporary image
    // that be used by OpenGL to produce a texture.
    byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) texImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    imageBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length);
    imageBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    imageBuffer.put(data, 0, data.length);
    imageBuffer.flip();

    return imageBuffer;
}

/**
 * Load a given resource as a buffered image
 * 
 * @param ref
 *            The location of the resource to load
 * @return The loaded buffered image
 * @throws IOException
 *             Indicates a failure to find a resource
 */
private BufferedImage loadImage(String ref) throws IOException {
    URL url = TextureLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(ref);
    if (url == null) {
        url = new URL("file:"+ref);
//          throw new IOException("Cannot find: " + ref);
    }
    System.out.println("URL:" + url);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream()));//this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ref)));

    return bufferedImage;
}

/**
 * Creates an integer buffer to hold specified ints - strictly a utility method
 * 
 * @param size
 *            how many int to contain
 * @return created IntBuffer
 */
protected IntBuffer createIntBuffer(int size) {
    ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * size);
    temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    return temp.asIntBuffer();
}
}
```

Comment: In graphics programming, it is always better to batch as much as possible. So don't try to cut your tileset into smaller ones, because this won't allow you to batch tiles from subset A together with tiles from subset B, because they are on another texture. There is no problem with having big textures loaded into the VRAM.

Comment: I was also thinking about cutting the actual `Image` and then create many different Texture... are you sure there isn't any problem in loading big textures. The thing is that I load that textures at least 600 tiles in the map, not counting the overlayers....
What is the correct way to handle tiles?

Comment: That depends on how big your tiles are and what hardware you will be deploying your application to. As long as you don't go over 2048*2048 you will be fine. But I think that 600 tiles will take more than this area.

Comment: I use 32x32 tile. The game is created to work in a window 1024x768. What do you think? I can load an entire tileset and then pass only the reference to it at each tile and then each tile will be able to load the texture in the tileset and show only the 32x32 Rectangle that I need?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it would probably be more beneficial to have the `Tileset` handle the texture coordinates when rendering to the GL_QUADS, rather than having it split the large image into small tiles. That way you only have one copy in memory (rather than two), and you reduce load time.

In addition, it can cache the large texture and simply draw the tiles using the texture coordinates that the `Tileset` class specifies, which will most likely speed up rendering.

For example, when you draw your `Map`, it will call `Tileset.drawTile(tileID)`. The drawTile method will perform the OpenGL draw call, and set the texcoords to the location of the tile you are drawing.

Edit: a hacky solution to highlight what I mean:

```
public class Tileset {

 private int tilesetImageHandle;

 private ArrayList<Tile> tiles;

 public Tile getTile(int tileIndex) {
    return tiles.get(tileIndex);
 }

 public void bindTexture() {
    glBindTexture(tilesetImageHandle);
 }

 // Methods to retrieve tileset subimage offsets in x and y directions

}

public class Tile {
 private Tileset tileset;
 private float u, v;

 public Tile(Tileset tileset, float u, float v)  {
    this.tileset = tileset;
    this.u = u;
    this.v = v;
 }

 public void draw(Point location) {
    tileset.bindTexture();

    glPushMatrix(GL_MODEL_VIEW_MATRIX);
    glTranslate2f(location.x, location.y);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(u, v);
    glCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
    glTexCoord2f(u, v + tileset.getTilesetOffsetY());
    glCoord2f(tileset.getTileDimX(), tileset.getTileDimY());
    glTexCoord2f(u + tileset.getTilesetOffsetX(), v + tileset.getTilesetOffsetY());
    glCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(u + tileset.getTilesetOffsetX(), v);

    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix(GL_MODEL_VIEW_MATRIX);
 }
}
```

The tileset class holds the GL handle to the tileset image.

The Tile class is used to render the tile based on the location provided and the tileset it belongs to (binds the image and draws the quad with the texcoords corresponding to the specific tile).

This doesn't illustrate everything, but I didn't have too much time to put it together, and I wasn't sure how you had implemented your application.

Comment: There isn't. You'd add LWJGL code to your TileSet class to have it handle GL commands.

If you'd like, I could come up with a quick demo later today.

Or if you want to send me a snippet of your code, we could work through it.

Comment: I'll go for the demo, If you like.

Comment: I added my actual code, is what I am trying to use, but it seems to slow down a lot the whole program, at least I am passing from 60fps to 40fps.
I am not able yet to draw the map because of the complex class that read the map from xml but I want to know if you think that this is the right way to follow...

I am talking about a map 50x50 tiles 32x32 3 layers full.

Comment: One thing you can do to speed up rendering is to pre-draw the map and store -that- as a texture. I assume right now you are drawing each tile on the map each frame. If the map doesn't scroll, you can draw it into a texture, save that texture, and then bind it to one big quad for the background of your scene.

Comment: actually it is scrolling, but I was thinking of render only the visible tiles, that should be something like 30x20 max

Comment: If the map doesn't scroll very often, you could get away with prerendering the tiles to a single texture, and re-rendering when the map changes. Either way, you will definitely only want to render the visible tiles. Rendering all of the tiles will still incur a performance hit even if OpenGL can optimize away some of the off-screen calls.

Comment: It scroll each single move that each player do. so there's no way to create a single tile

Comment: I've fixed some code, removed some "trace" println, disallowed the program to trying paint null tiles. I am between 55 and 70 fps, depending on the monitor I am using.

Comment: That sounds pretty good -- a common FPS target for games is 60.

Hope it keeps working well!